# My facebook comments are not visible for all visitors

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i have problem with facebook comments on my page.
Posts which make visitors are not visible. Posts are visible but only which i will make and then when i logout it will disappear.

```
/*part of header.php*/
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{hereisadminid}" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{hereisappid}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $row['title']; ?> | Yrrej" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $row['title_uri']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?= $row['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.something.sk/og_something.png" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=hereisappid";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Then in body of my website, under each article is this

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.yrrej.eu/<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" data-       numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Can you help me someone, what is wrong when i cant see all comments? Thanks for tips and help :( Here is my website [www.yrrej.eu](http://www.yrrej.eu)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your source code, you've written ID's in meta tags with `{***}`, pls remove the `{` and `}`

Second thing, please check that your app is not in the development mode. If it is, you can change the status to live in the settings in "Status & Review"

Comment: Finally comments are visible but my facebook like button and comments have bug ...when like is given or comemnts are posted on facebook wall it will show error message and it will crash. Title and description from og tags are working ...Any suggestions what is wrong?:( link on my website [yrrej.eu](http://yrrej.eu), thank :/

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand since your website is in different language

Comment: Ou, so it is all about that it will crash after i will give "paci sa mi to" - like button under article. I have no idea why :(. ...Console says event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: How a website crashes? O.o

Comment: :D ok sorry for my english all website is not crushed, just facebook like button wont work when is pressed :P but it should work

Comment: Explain what actually is happening by editing your question. Any error you are getting or what is happening actually. Else its difficult for us to understand

Comment: Just try press facebook like button(paci sa mi to) under article and will see what is my problem, if you can? [http://yrrej.eu/facebook-kupil-tvorcov-okuliarov-oculus-za-2-miliardy](http://yrrej.eu/facebook-kupil-tvorcov-okuliarov-oculus-za-2-miliardy)

Comment: The like is successful. Its even posted on my wall. That I liked this page. What's the problem?

Comment: You liked fan page but not article :P there is like button right under the article together with comments :) This one is not working as should work